# Prepare Dynamic Lambda Expression with Checking parentproperty null control

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have dynamic lambda expression tree,I prepare my expression and compile it.

My problem is when I prepare expression something like

```
MyClass1.Property2.ChildProperty1=="xyz";
```

if Property2 is null then I take nullrefence error.

```
public class MyClass1
{
    public string Property1{get;set;}
    public MyClass2 Property2{get;set;}
}

public class MyClass2
{
    public string ChildProperty1{get;set;}
    public string ChildProperty2{get;set;}
}

public Func<T, bool> CompileRule<T>(Rule r)
{
     ...
     Func<T, bool> myfunc =Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expr, paramUser).Compile();
     ...
     return myfunc;
}
```

Another function I execute my request like " myfunc(myrequest); "

Is there a generic way to check null control when I preprare my expression in CompileTime,If ParentProperty null then return false for these statement?In compile method I dont have entity ,so I have to prepare statement with check null control

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, but you could use the null conditional operator from C# 6: `MyClass1?.Property2?.ChildProperty == "xyz"`. That will return false if `MyClass1` is null, or `MyClass1.Property2` is null. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes I want to that but I Prepare this statement dynamically.Is there a generic way to that I prepare my expression something like that.Expression.Constant(r.TargetValue, typeof(string)) and Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, item.Key), Expression.Constant(item.Value));...

Comment: @j0ey_wh: You didn't format the code - you *undid* the formatting from my previous edit.

Comment: It's not at all clear what `r.TargetValue`, `parameter`, `item.Key` or `item.Value` are. From early on in the code it looks like you're using a lambda expression, but now it sounds like you're not. We can't really help you while we're having to guess at what you're trying to achieve. Please edit this into a [mcve].

Comment: I create dynamic lambda expression in runtime and compile it and execute after all.What I want if parent property is null then add null check to my expression without that I take null reference error when  my parent property is null.When I prepare my expression I use c# lambda methods like Expression.Equal,Expression.constant like that

Comment: Rather than trying to explain your question briefly in a comment, please take the time to explain it problem *in the question*, with a [mcve].

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355194/building-a-microruleengine-using-linqexpressions  I use same code block in this question

Comment: Each Stack Overflow question should stand alone. SO aims to be a repository of good questions and answers - not a breadcrumb trail.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to create dynamically a body of an expression like this:

```
Expression<Func<MyClass1, string>> expr = 
    x => x.Property2?.ChildProperty1;
```

Unfortunately currently there is not standard `Expression` method supporting that. If you try the above, you'll get a compile time error:

> > Error CS8072  An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator.

One possible way is to generate a body of an expression like this instead:

```
Expression<Func<MyClass1, string>> expr = 
    x => x.Property2 != null ? x.Property2.ChildProperty1 : null;
```

It's not the exact equivalent, but should work.

Here is a sample snippet which does that dynamically:

```
string memberPath = ...; // e.g. "Property2.ChildProperty2"
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
Expression result;
if (memberPath.IndexOf('.') < 0)
    result = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, memberPath);
else
{
    var memberNames = memberPath.Split('.');
    var members = new Expression[memberNames.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < memberNames.Length; i++)
        members[i] = Expression.PropertyOrField(i > 0 ? members[i - 1] : parameter, memberNames[i]);
    result = members[members.Length - 1];
    // For non nullable value types, promote the result into the corresponding nullable type
    if (result.Type.IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(result.Type) == null)
        result = Expression.Convert(result, typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(result.Type));
    var nullResult = Expression.Constant(null, result.Type);
    for (int i = members.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        result = Expression.Condition(
            Expression.NotEqual(members[i], Expression.Constant(null)),
            result, nullResult);
    }
}
```

At the end, the `result` variable contains the expression that you can use for left side of the comparison predicate.

Comment: I have another expression like Expression.MakeBinary(tBinary, propExpression, right) as result something {(Param_0.Body.No == 6)},How can I combine with these expressions .I try but got he binary operator AndAlso is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' and 'System.Boolean'.

Comment: var a =AccessMember(r.MemberName, paramExp);
                var b = Expression.MakeBinary(tBinary, propExpression, right), Expression.AndAlso(a, b);

Comment: You might need to convert `right` to the type of the `left`. e.g. `if (right.Type != left.Type) right = Expression.Convert(right, left.Type);`

Comment: I convert but still get The binary operator AndAlso is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' and 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' error

Comment: They shouldn't be `int` (or `Nullable<int>`) expression types at all. `AndAlso` needs `bool` expressions. In your sample, `a` should be the `left` and if `right` is converted to the `left` type, `var b = Expression.MakeBinary(tBinary, left, right),` should be of `bool` type. If you post the full code, I could take a look at it.

Comment: Your code block return  --> result {IIF((SomeObject.Body != null), Convert(SomeObject.Body.No), null)} and type is -->  result.Type {Name = "Nullable`1" FullName = "System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}

Comment: Yes indeed. Read the end of the answer. The `result` variable is what you need to use as `left` operand in `Expression.MakeBinary` call. It's not the result of the comparison `MyClass1.Property2.ChildProperty1=="xyz"`, just the left operand `MyClass1.Property2.ChildProperty1`. The designator for the `propExpression` variable from the link.